# Why is there an infinite loop on my LostFocus Event

Tags: c#, events, textbox, infinite-loop, lostfocus

I'm a beginner with C# and I'm developing a basic application.
I want to check if the value of a textbox is a number with the following code :

```
private void check_value(object sender)
    {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender ;
        if (!Utility.isNumeric(tb.Text)){
            MessageBox.Show(tb.Text.Length.ToString());
            tb.Focus();
        }
    }

    private void Amount_1_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        check_value(sender);
    }
```

When I enter a letter in the textbox there is an infinite loop and it seems that the tb.Focus() actually cause the LostFocus event to be call recursively.
I don't understand why the call to the Focus method of an object triggers the LostFocus event of the same object.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code? I could be incorrect but I would assume that the MessageBox.Show() is causing the textbox to lose focus and cause the infinite loop.

Comment: Yes i have, it display the message, call the Focus(), exit the check_value (and then go back to his parent, the LostFocus method), go to the last parenthesis of the LostFocus and then go back to the first parenthesis, and so on...  Plus, the call to the focus method is after the messagebox so it should give the focus anyway

Comment: In the link given by xaqron there is the following message : "Do not attempt to set focus from within the Enter, GotFocus, Leave, LostFocus, Validating, or Validated event handlers. Doing so can cause your application or the operating system to stop responding." So all i can do is find another way to validate the value.

Answer (score 5):

Opening the modal `MessageBox` is responsible for loosing the focus. Try hook to `Validating` event.

Comment: I don't have any validating event attached to my textbox, I tried to add a private void Amount_1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) but it's not called when I click on another field.

Comment: `CausesValidation` property should be set to true. see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx

Comment: I don't have this property either, i'm trying to develop a WPF project if it changes something.

Answer (score 0):

As i said before in the link provided by Xaqron it's said that it's forbidden to use the Focus method in the LostFocus event.
And as I'm developing a WPF application there is no Validating event and CausesValidation property, so the others ways to validate the content is to use the TextChanged event or use binding validation.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, in a perfectly valid program, you should not change Focus in the LostFocus event. This also applies to the Enter, GotFocus, Leave, Validating and Validated events, which Ms makes clear in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus.
However, in very unusual cases, you can use the timer to trigger changes to the Focus, bypassing this problem.

```
private TextBox tb = null;
private System.Windows.Forms.Timer MyTimer;

private void initialize()
{
    MyTimer.Tick += new System.EventHandler(MyTimer_Tick);
    MyTimer.Enable = false;
    MyTimer.Interval = 100;
}

private void check_value(object sender)
{
    tb = (TextBox)sender ;
    if (!Utility.isNumeric(tb.Text)){
        MessageBox.Show(tb.Text.Length.ToString());
        MyTimer.Enable = true;
    }
}

private void Amount_1_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    check_value(sender);
}

private void MyTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyTimer.Enabled = false;
    if (tb!=null) tb.Focus();
}
```